# How to make systemd maintain 'after' dependency when restarting slow services

Tags: systemd, dependencies

In our system we have 2 dependencies, say A and B, where A has an 'after' dependency on B.

In certain scenarios we want to restart both services at once. The issue is that B stops gracefully and so takes a long time. A finishes stopping first, and instantly restarts because its dependency on B is met. Then B restarts after A, not the other way round.

The behaviour we want is for A to not restart until B has finished stopping and restarted itself.

Is there a systemd setting that can fix this? Does BindsTo give the behaviour we want?

Answer (score 1):

If every time you restart `B` you want to also have `A` restarted then you can either use the [`BindsTo=B` + `After=B`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#BindsTo=) directives in service `A`.
Alternatively, for a more "dirty" but maybe less systemd reliant approach, you can add the restart command of service `A`using the [`ExecStartPost=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStartPre=) directive under `B`'s unit file.

This will ensure that every time service `B` is started (or restarted), it also forces a restart on service `A`.